# Building an Xpage for searching issue

Tags: lotus, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm having a great deal of trouble with this searching page I'm building.

I have a view with documents with fields like the following: foreignCompany, ourCompany, dateStarted, dateEnded, countryOfApplication. The user enters the following parameters to search: company name (foreignCompany), date (we'll call this searchDate) and countryOfApplication.

The results show the companies that have valid contracts between the dateStarted - searchDate - dateEnded.
I've partially achieved this so far.

The problem is, if the company name is for instance: Kompanija, but the user enters: Komp or Kom or Kompanij or whatever, but not Kompanija, the search returns no results!? Only if the whole word is entered is when there are results returned.

I even followed the example from IBM help, How to build an Xpage for searching, same thing happens with that too.

I'd very much appreciate any help that's given here, since I've been busting my head against the wall for quite some time now.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the query you are using to search for the company 'Komp'?

Comment: Additional to that: how are you searching? Using a standard database.search or using the FTsearch method on a view?

Comment: Can you send the query you have build?

Comment: this is the query: Query = (FIELD foreignCompany= "kompan") AND (FIELD countryOfApplication = "Македонија") AND (FIELD countryOfApplication2 = "Србија")

I have no idea how to search with the date parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using search property on the view data source, then be aware that the search property uses the Notes Full Text search "language" for the search query - e.g. [Publish]="1" AND [Status]="Finished".

This will search for parts of a company name using your example:

```
[foreignCompany] CONTAINS Komp
```

So you probably need to modify your search query.

Comment: How do you build the search query and pass it to the search property on the view data source in your current solution? Please update your question with example code

Comment: I was having some issues with pasting the code here, so here's a link to Pastebin http://pastebin.com/3gyR9y5E

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it...

Comment: ugh... I'm getting an error: Notes error: Query is not understandable

If it matters I need to search with cyrillic values.

Comment: Have a look at sessionScope.queryString and see how the search query looks like when generated

Comment: This is the result:`[foreignCompany] CONTAINS "kompan") AND     [countryOfApplication] CONTAINS "Македонија") AND     [countryOfApplication2] CONTAINS "Србија") AND [ourCompany] CONTAINS "Име на Компанијата"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8443/discussion-between-per-henrik-lausten-and-gkidd)

Comment: This is funny, now you have to type at least four letters of the word.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a query like

> Query = (FIELD foreignCompany= "kompan") AND (FIELD
>   countryOfApplication = "Македонија") AND (FIELD countryOfApplication2
>   = "Србија")

its obvious that results only return a foreigncompany which complete name is kompan. You should use something like this (use contains..)

> Query = (FIELD [foreignCompany] contains "kompan") AND (FIELD
>   [countryOfApplication] CONTAINS "Македонија") AND (FIELD [countryOfApplication2]
>   = "Србија")

How you can accomplish this @runtime. You could use a ssjs Function 'generateQuery()' where you pass in the string you are searching for and it generates a correct query. Something like

```
function generateQuery(strforeignCompany, strcountryOfApplication , strcountryOfApplication2){
    var strQuery = new java.lang.StringBuffer();

    if(strForeignCompany != null && !"".equals(strForeignCompany)){
 strQuery.append("[ForeignCompany] contains");
 strQuery.append(strForeignCompany);
    }


    if(strcountryOfApplication != null && !"".equals(strcountryOfApplication )){
 strQuery.append("[countryOfApplication ] contains");
 strQuery.append(strcountryOfApplication );
    }


    if(strcountryOfApplication2!= null && !"".equals(strcountryOfApplication2)){
 strQuery.append("[countryOfApplication2] contains");
 strQuery.append(strcountryOfApplication2);
    }
  return strQuery.toString();
 }
```

Comment: I've fixed the code but it was meant to be a sample code, no production code ;)